# Using filter functions in cql_filter throws "... cannot be cast to org.opengis.filter.Filter"

Tags: geoserver, cql-filter

I'm trying to use CQL filters in WFS, like (with proper URL encoding):

```
&cql_filter=strEqualsIgnoreCase(name, 'Jane Doe')
&cql_filter=strMatches(name, '(?i).* doe')
```

But this tells me, e.g.:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.geotools.filter.function.FilterFunction_strMatches cannot be cast to org.opengis.filter.Filter

The [CQL and ECQL](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html#filter-functions) documentation claims:

> CQL/ECQL can use any of the [filter functions](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#filter-function-reference) available in GeoServer.

The functions I'm trying to use are listed there, and I can indeed use *some* of the other functions, like the following works just fine:

```
&cql_filter=strToLowerCase(name) like '% doe'
```

However, many other functions throw an error like above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is simple: anything that yields a boolean value must be explicitly compared to `true`. Like (with proper URL encoding):

```
&cql_filter=strEqualsIgnoreCase(name, 'Jane Doe') = true
&cql_filter=strMatches(name, '(?i).* doe') = true
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, this error pops up when I export an SLD style from QGIS and load it into geoserver.

Specifically, in my styles the 'escape' and 'rotation' and 'dingbats' are where the errors sit.

```
escape --> escapeChar
<se:Rotation\> --> <se:Rotation></se:Rotation>
D050000L --> Dingbats
```

I'm sure there are others, and upgrades, and the like.  But these types of nits often come up in Geoserver's Java parsing.